# Selecting the first and last value in a column in a group by query

Tags: sql

I have a transaction level table. I am attempting to consolidate it to a acct level table. As such, I have aggregated a number of fields. However, for text based fields, I would like the first and last values for each acct.

In Access there is a LAST function. I tried to replicate the logic of this function here:

```
SELECT

ACCT
,(SELECT TOP 1 PaidDte FROM TRANS_TBL
WHERE MSTR_TRANS_TYPE = 'Paid' and ACCT=ACCT ORDER BY DTE DESC) as  'LastPaid'

FROM TRANS_TBL
GROUP BY ACCT
```

All this did was return the last value of the entire table in every acct record and not the last value for a sub-query for each distinct account.

Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this? I have done it before, I just can't remember how it works.

Thanks!

Comment: what makes an entry the "first" or the "last" entry for an account?  Are you using an datetime or preferably an auto incrementing ID?  What is your table schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, if you provide more of your schema it could probably be refined a bit more:

```
select   acct -- select whatever you need from the min and max records for each acct
from     trans_table t
inner    join (
    select   acct
             min(Dte) as minDte,
             max(Dte) as maxDte)
    from     TRANS_TBL -- i'm assuming DTE stands for date (don't use abbreviations and then not explain your schema :p ) this would be better if you had an auto id in case of exactly overlapping dates.
    GROUP    BY acct
) minMaxDates on t.acct = minMaxDates.acct
    and (
        t.Dte = minMaxDates.minDte OR 
        t.Dte = minMapDte.maxDte
    )
```